# How do I check user's unlocked achievement and leaderboard scores via GPG plugin

Tags: unity, android, google-play-services

I need to load user's achievement and their scores from leaderboard in my game. But the `Social.LoadScore()` and `Social.LoadAchievements()` both returns a 0 size array in callback.

When I checked the implementation in Google Play Gaming's PlayGamePlatform.cs, both the method has this summary -

```
Not implemented yet. Calls the callback with an empty list.
```

So my question is How do I get this data in Unity? Has anyone tried any other method to get the data?

Comment: Same issue here and finally for the sake of time, I compromised and satisfied my self with `Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();`

Comment: So did I. I actually needed the data to show custom notification about which achievement is left to unlock and which is already unlocked.

Comment: Sadly, the plugin is lacking a lot of features.